# Add chrome web driver in RIDE (robot framework)

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, selenium2library

I am new to robot framework.

I have put the `chromedriver.exe` file in the path of system. Now, when I am running scripts in RIDE I am getting this error:

`WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home`

Is there is any other way of setting path in RIDE itself?

**UPDATE: My path variable includes:
`C:\Driver\chromedriver.exe;`**

Comment: After putting chromedriver.exe file in the path of system, have you restarted your system so that the changes get effected?

Comment: @ShoaibAkhtar i have tried this, but it is not working

Comment: Add the code also in your question that you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the Robot framework installation guide,How to set the environment variables.
Place the chrome driver in te path "C:\Python\Scripts" and make sure this path "C:\Python\Scripts" is updated in environment variables.If you have any clarification check the below link.Under the heading Setting PATH on Windows

https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/INSTALL.rst

Answer (score 1):

Download Chromedriver.exe from its official website, extract the .exe file and copy this .exe file in scripts folder of Python installation, e.g. C:\Python36\Scripts

After this, add this scripts path in Environment variable